# Removing UTF 8 encoding in python

Tags: python, list, utf-8, web-scraping

I tried scraping the webpage for Passengers & Cargo data. I couldn't convert them into normal data, and web encoding seems to be the challenge.

The Code I used is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib 
url = "https://www.faa.gov/data_research/passengers_cargo/unruly_passengers/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find_all("tbody")

for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

Output1

[image]

This prints in the format Year and Total. But when I append it to a list, the encoding ruins the data. You can see that in Output1

```
names = []
for link in links:
    names.append(link.text)
names = map(lambda x: x.strip().encode('ascii'), names)
print(names)
```

Output2

[image]

The desired output should be Years and Total for me to perform analyses

Comment: `\n` are line breaks, that you can easily replace or split at.

Comment: It's not ruining your data. Your data is fine. It still contains exactly the same characters as before; it's just displayed differently from how it would be if you `print`ed the strings directly.

Comment: Note that the code you actually ran doesn't include the `map(lambda x: x.strip().encode('ascii'), names)` step, and that the `encode('ascii')` part probably isn't necessary.

Comment: If you `print(len(links))` you might learn something.

Comment: As all of them have mentioned, I think splitting the string makes most sense. You can then get them into a list and splice the list into even and odd element arrays or pandas dataframe columns for your analysis.

Comment: Thank you all. I found the solution. I created a dataframe with two columns Years and Total

Comment: list.split('\n') may work , and then just pop the empty elements made due to simultaneous newline characters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find_all `tr` and `td` like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib 
url = "https://www.faa.gov/data_research/passengers_cargo/unruly_passengers/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find_all("tr")

data = []
for link in links:
    tds = link.find_all('td')
    if tds:
        data.append({'year':tds[0].text,'total':tds[1].text})

print(data)
```

It's worked.

Hope it helps you